# create phpmyadmin user for selected database access only

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, privileges

I need to create a user in php myadmin.
Say user -> aaa  and Password -> aaa123

Now  I want this new user aa to access only one database out of the multiple database in the phppmyadmin.

Any suggestion is mst welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Create the user with only that database permission.

use the command:

grant all on db_name.* to 'username'@'localhost';

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say that a single  database of your choice is displayed in phpmyadmin and not all the databases in the phpmyadmin , for several reasons.

Well  , answer for this is Yes , you can do that.

You need to install phpmyadmin in your server settings account, click on server settings  , and then  "Add the list of severs to be allowed in that "list.